# Android activity flag issue

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have my launcher activity flag set to singleTop.

when I launch activity from notification bar (with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in receiver), new activity is created and the previous one is not used.
What can be done to have only one activity in stack?

Edit:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
```

in receiver, seem to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

"Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" makes launched activity behaves differently. Whenever I launch activity form history It always calls onNewIntent

Answer (score 0):

use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn use of these different flags. use the link below, it will ne helpful.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK